# How to set environment variables for a terminal application on OS X Yosemite?

Tags: terminal, environment-variables, osx-yosemite

I am trying to make ABD tool to work in my terminal and I found that the likely reason why I get the command not found warning is that I need to set the environment variable's path.

I found that I have to modify the `~/.profile` file but when I try to it does not let me. It claims I have no permissions and offers to make a copy even though I use Textedit.app in superuser mode.

What do I need to do to edit this file?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sudo nano ~/.profile`textedit can have quite a few issues when dealing with bash in my experience.